# How can I loop adding items to the list?

Tags: python

How can I loop adding items to 'list'?

```
url = 'https://api.com/api/v1/products?app_id=web02'

response = requests.get(url).json()

items = response['data']
iter1 = []
for item in items:
   iter1.append({
     'name': item.get('name', 'NA'),
     'owner': item.get('owner', 'NA'),
     'date_published': item.get('date_published', 'NA'),
     'images': item.get('images', 'NA'),
     'short_url': item.get('short_url', 'NA')
   })

list = []
for list in iter1:
    result = {}
    result["name"] = iter1[0]["name"]
    result["user"] = iter1[1]["owner"]["name"]
    result["date_published"] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(iter1[0]["date_published"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    result["url"] = []
    result["short_url"] = iter1[0]["short_url"]

    for img in iter1[0]["images"]:
        result["url"].append(img["url"])
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Now I always have only one processed earlier block in the "result" variable.

Comment: It's poor practice to name a variable in python the same thing as a built-in. I would recommend changing `list` to something else more descriptive. Also, how many items are in `iter1[0]["images"]` (you can use the `len()` method to check this)?

Comment: With this `list = []; for list in iter1:` the initialised list is overwritten immediately with the iteration element.

Comment: what items do you want to add in the list?

Comment: I can't reproduce this because the call to `requests.get(url)` fails for me. Can you update your question with a small sample of what you see in `items`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is wrong.

```py
list = []
for list in iter1:
```

then you use the is `iter1` instead `list`

```py
result = {}
result["name"] = iter1[0]["name"]
```

Try not using `list` because it's a class reserved to `list` type

```
Python 3.9.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 21 2021, 05:00:30)
[Clang 11.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>> []
[]
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>
>>>
```